# loop properties of javascript object

Tags: javascript

i have a function that loop all object properties and return value if it qualify certain condition

basically this is how i m doing

```
  //an enum    
 var BillingType = Object.freeze({
    PayMonthly: { key: 'Monthly', value: 1 },
    PayYearly: { key: 'Yearly', value: 2 }
});
```

now to make it work i do this

```
   for (var property in BillingType ) {
        if (BillingType .hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (value === BillingType [property].value) {
                return BillingType [property].key;
            }
        }
    }
```

it works fine but to make it generic for all enums i changed code to

```
getValue = function (value, object) {
    for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (value === object[property].value) {
                return object[property].key;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now when i try to call from other functions

```
 enumService.getValue(1, 'BillingModel');
```

rather to loop all properties it start loop on its characters.

how can i convert string to object or m doing it totally wrong . any help will be appreciated

Regards

Comment: What you do with the two objects BillingModel and BillingType is strange. And why do you pass the name of the object instead of the object ? Did you want `enumService.getValue(1, BillingModel);`?

Comment: You want to pass the `BillingType` variable (your enum object), not the `'BillingModel'` string?!

Comment: my mistake Guys . you all are right thanks for helping me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getValue` looks fine, just call it using

```
enumService.getValue(1, BillingModel); // <-- no quotes
```

and here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LVc6G/

and here is the code of the fiddle:

```
var BillingType = Object.freeze({
    PayMonthly: { key: 'Monthly', value: 1 },
    PayYearly: { key: 'Yearly', value: 2 }
});

var getValue = function (value, object) {
    for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (value === object[property].value) {
                return object[property].key;
            }
        }
    }
};

alert(getValue(1, BillingType));
```

Comment: You're welcome :) If my answer helped you feel free to upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: i just cant accept answer in 6 minutes :S SO restriction